# Header and foot always visible

Tags: css

Until now I have mostly worked on the back-end, but I have to do some front-end also at the moment.

I have to make a web-page like the following:

```
   +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                                     |
   |    Header                                                           |
   |                                                                     |
   |       +------------------------------------------------------+      |
   |       |                                                      |      |
   |  G    |                                                      |      |
   |  r    |                                                      |      |
   |  a    |                                                      |      |
   |  d    |                                                    S |      |
   |  i    |                                                    c |      |
   |  e    |                                                    r |      |
   |  n    |                                                    o |      |
   |  t    |                                                    l |      |
   |       |                                                    l |      |
   |       |                                                    b |      |
   |       |                                                    a |      |
   |       |                                                    r |      |
   |       |                                                      |      |
   |       |                                                      |      |
   |       +------------------------------------------------------+      |
   |                                                                     |
   |    Footer                                                           |
   |                                                                     |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The outer box should always fill the complete window: the header and footer should always be visible. When the screen estate is not big enough the inner box (that contains the content) should become scrollable.

Beside this there should also be a gradient from top to bottom.

Is this possible with CSS? If so, how would I do this?

EDIT:
I think I solved it. Partly because I got a lot of related questions (I searched, but did not find, but the related questions showed the way) and partly because of the answer of 
’IP ADDRESS’.

With those helps I made now the following, what seems to do what I need:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang = "nl" lang = "nl">

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height:           100%;
        margin:           0px;
      }

      #container {
        background:       linear-gradient(blue, white);
        height:           100%;
        margin:           auto;
        width:            100%;
      }

      #main {
        overflow:         auto;
      }

      #content {
        background-color: white;
        border:           1px solid black;
        border-radius:    10px;
        margin-left:      auto ;
        margin-right:     auto ;
      }

      #footer {
        height:           auto;
        margin:           auto;
        position:         relative;
        width:            100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
      function doResize() {
        var footer_height    = $('#footer').height()
        footer_height       += 2
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', '-' + footer_height + 'px')
        $('#main').css('padding-bottom', footer_height + 'px')
        var footer_position  = $('#footer').offset().top + window.screenY
        var content_position = $('#content').offset().top + window.screenY
        var newHeight        = footer_position - content_position - 2
        var newWidth         = $(document).width() - 100
        $('#content').css({
          'height': newHeight,
          'width':  newWidth
        })
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        doResize()
      })
      $(window).resize(function() {
        doResize()
      })
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="header"><div class="header">Header</div></div>
            <div id="content">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><div class="footer">Footer</div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is far too broad.

Comment: You really need to have a go yourself and post some code. No one will be willing to simply come along and do your work for you. That's not meant to be harsh btw. We all want to help each other with figuring out solutions but it's best to have a go yourself first of all.

Comment: @BillyMoat he drew a pretty diagram though, that must have taken ages

Comment: You need CSS to position "fixed" your header and footer, but also some javaScript to do those validations you need. Here's an example of how to fix a header http://natyoung.co.uk/

Comment: @rorypicko, I totally didn't downvote because of the quality of the Ascii art!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS>>>

```
 <div id="container" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red , blue); height:100%;width:100%;">
 <div id="header">
    Header
 </div>

 <div style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
 <div id="sroll_box" style="width:250px;height:200px;overflow:auto;background-color:brown;text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    Content
 </div></div>

 <div id="footer">
    Footer
 </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6FLMz/

Please comment back if you need more help.thanks